# How can I shorten these repetitive while/try/except/else input blocks?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make an exchange app and I am trying to make it shorter (mostly by changing those whiles).

```
def key_check(currency):
    import re
    rates = website["rates"]
    rates.update({"EUR": 1})
    rates = json.dumps(rates)
    if not re.search(currency, rates):
        raise Exception(
            "This is not a currency")
    else:
        rates = json.loads(rates)


while True:
    try:
        yourCurrency = input("Which currency do you have?: ").upper()
        key_check(yourCurrency)
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
    else:
        break

while True:
    try:
        yourMoney = float(input("How much money do you have?: "))
    except:
        print("This is not a float!")
    else:
        break

while True:
    try:
        exchangeCurrency = input(
            "Which currency would you like to buy?: ").upper()
        key_check(exchangeCurrency)
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Why does it need to be shorter?

Comment: I want to learn not to use so many whiles and I don't know what to do in these cases. I tried using an if but I guess I couldn't find the right statement.

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with the following solution and I had quite a bit of fun writing it.

```py
class Input:
    def __init__(self, question, required_type, check_against = None):
        self.question = question
        self.required_type = required_type
        self.check_against = check_against

    def get(self):
        while True:
            try:
                answer = self.required_type(input(self.question))
                if self.check_against:
                    assert self.check_against(answer)
                return answer
            except (ValueError, AssertionError):
                pass
```

Example usage

```py
def isTen(a):
    return isinstance(a, int) and a == 10

print(Input("Number: ", int, isTen).get())
```

This will force the user to keep entering until the correct value is given, example output

```
Number: test
Number: 123
Number: 10.0
Number: 10
10
>>>
```

You can handle error messages in the `check_against` optional parameter, for example

```py
def isTen(a):
    if isinstance(a, int) and a == 10:
        print("Good job!")
        return True
    print("Bad input, give me TEN")
    return False
```

If you want an error message when the type is incorrect, you can manually add that into the `get` function or make it a parameter in the class constructor.

## Edit

This is how it might look in your code

```py
yourCurrency = Input("Which currency do you have?: ", str, key_check).get()
yourMoney = Input("How much money do you have?: ", float).get()
exchangeCurrency = Input("Which currency would you like to buy?: ", str, key_check).get()
print(f"You have {yourMoney} {yourCurrency} and would like to buy {exchangeCurrency}")
```

Results in

```
Which currency do you have?: GBP
How much money do you have?: 650.30
Which currency would you like to buy?: USD
You have 650.3 GBP and would like to buy USD
```

Comment: I tried to apply this to my code but I couldn't and even though if I could it might be even longer

Comment: It's 15 lines long (white space included), then +3, because you're asking the user for 3 inputs giving a total line count of 18, whereas your current three while loops *without whitespace*, is 25 lines + your three inputs is 28 - so no, it's considerably shorter. If you add more inputs, the benefit of my answer will be even more apparent.

Comment: Can you apply your code to mine please because I couldn't

Comment: @Condign I've added another example to my answer for your original usage

Comment: The problem in here is I am trying to check if the answer is in the dictionary and by using your code I couldn't do that

Comment: From the code you provided in the question, you only raise an exception if it's not in the dictionary otherwise the result of `key_check` is ignored. You can modify `key_check` to return true if it's in the dictionary, false if otherwise. Or you could make another function, say, `validateCurrency` which calls `key_check` and returns false if it raises an exception, true if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The following code doesn't work **exactly** like the provided sample, but very similar (the difference is in what it prints in case of an exception)

```py
# Always place your imports at the very top of file
import re
from traceback import format_exc


def key_check(currency):
    rates = website["rates"]
    rates.update({"EUR": 1})
    rates = json.dumps(rates)
    if not re.search(currency, rates):
        raise Exception("This is not a currency")
    else:
        rates = json.loads(rates)

    # Make key_check return the given value back to make our life easier :)
    return currency


def want_input(s, handler=None):
    if handler is None:
        handler = lambda x: x

    while True:
        try:
            var = handler(input(s))
        #except KeyboardInterrupt:
            #print("In your place I would handle KeyboardInterrupt separately and make it stop the execution of the program")
        except:
            print(format_exc())
        else:
            return var


yourCurrency = want_input("Which currency do you have?: ", lambda x: key_check(x.upper()))

yourMoney = want_input("How much money do you have?: ", lambda x: float(x))

exchangeCurrency = want_input("Which currency would you like to buy?: ", lambda x: key_check(x.upper()))
```

(didn't run it, but must work)

Comment: Sorry, there was a bug, fixed just now. Btw, if you don't to return anything from `key_check`, you can, for example, add one more parameter to `want_input`: a function (or an array of functions?) to be evaluated inside `try-except` block

Comment: Thanks for your time but the code is more complicated now and it's not really that shorter from before :(